# Where does TFS keep information on how projects within a solution are structured?

Tags: tfs

Is it just in csproj files and the solution file or are there other files or locations where information is stored? What are those vssscc files doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS source control generally does not care how the content put in it is stored or structured. The .vssscc files are just a hold-over from the previous Visual Studio integration, and are only used by TFS to list file exclusions from source control (as far as I know, anyway...there could be undocumented uses as well.) Your solution and project structure is defined by your solution and project files. TFS Source control simply tracks the different versions of any file put in it, and provides ways to find and analyze that version data.

Comment: +1 that's pretty much it.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/richardb/archive/2007/06/04/intro-to-solution-binding-in-tfs-plus-bonus-faq.aspx for details.

Answer (score 0):

JRista's answer is pretty close.  I'm not aware of any uses for the .vssscc file other than exclusions.  Even within the .sln/.csproj files, there are no explicit bindings, just a bunch of "SAK" entries that tell VS not to do anything special.  In the end, the layout of the projects on disk is determined by workspace mappings; the structure of the solution itself is determined by the paths in the .sln file.

Obviously the two need to match.  If you have nonstandard workspace mappings, some projects may not load.  If some of the paths referred to in the .sln are not mapped at all, VS will create explicit mappings during Add To SCC and Open From SCC operations.  This can be problematic -- people who don't map their code correctly in the first place often have unusual relative paths between their projects that can't be easily replicated by people trying to Get their code from source control.